# Specifying which python version to pip install to

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, package, plotly

I'm having troubles when trying to download and run packages within python, using pip install. Often pip will tell me that I have the package downloaded, but when I try to use the function it gives me an error and says 'no such file or directory'. It seems to me that I am using 2.7.10 and that is where pip is trying to install to, but I can't get why this isn't working

```
Peters-MBP:~ pete$ python import plotly
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Peters-MBP:~ pete$ pip install plotly
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): plotly in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Collecting pytz (from plotly)
  Using cached pytz-2016.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from plotly)
Collecting six (from plotly)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, six
Successfully installed pytz-2016.3 six-1.10.0
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Peters-MBP:~ pete$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
Peters-MBP:~ pete$ python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: AKA `f***d up environment`. Try reinstalling both python and pip.

Comment: Are You using virtualenvs?

Comment: No guys, it’s nothing that complicated.  Look at what he’s doing:  He’s trying to execute `python import plotly` at the shell prompt!!

Comment: So the f**ked up environment is kinda what I had been thinking. So should i just uninstall everything python related on my computer, and then reinstall all of this?

Comment: @PWalton Read the answers posted below by both myself and Marco.  You can’t do what you’re trying to do.  In all probability, your Python installation is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t just import a module on the command line like that(!!!):

```
$ python import plotly
```

Instead, do this:

First start the interactive Python interpreter:

```
$ python
```

Then, at the Python prompt, import your installed module:

```
>>> import plotly
```

Or, of course, put the `import` statement in a script and execute that script.

---

**Edit:**  If you try to run `python install plotly` at the shell prompt, as you did, the Python interpreter will look for a script called `install` in the current directory, in order to execute it.  Since no such script exists, it gives the error `can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense! Should anything pop up when I do that? Or should it just go to the next line?

Comment: @PWalton if the import is successful, it will be silent, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade 'pip install --upgrade pip'
Then try to upgrade also plotly and check it again.

Please post if the plotly module is visible in the Python27 installation folder.

In addition you should go inside the "python interpreter" to import a module.

Just try to

```
> python
import plotly
```

Comment: I've tried to upgrade pip, but I get:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0.dist-info/RECORD'

Should i just try to uninstall and reinstall a clean version of python to start over?

Comment: I have just upgrade my pip from 8.1.0 to 8.1.1 without issue. It would be great if you can share the commands you are running. Pip installation/upgrade has usually no issue. What about your plotly? Have you tried it within python interpreter?          C:\Windows\System32>pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)